# How to access a vector in base class from derived class?

Tags: c++

*Note: I'm sorry if it's a very simple question as I'm new to C++. And I did google it first before posting question, but it seems like I didn't find anything similar to my situation.

I have a vector as a private member in base class, and I want to access it from a derived class. What should I do?

I know private member cannot be directly access from derived class, and I must use a set get function. However, in this case, I have no idea how to return a vector by using get function. Below is an example:

```
class A
{
private:
vector<char> letter;
public:
...
}

class B : public A
{
public:
// Do something with letter
...
}
```

This can simply solved by changing it to protected, but that's not really what I want. So any other suggest?

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains what references are and how to use them, and implement a getter that returns this class member by reference.

Comment: protected keyword makes your field reachable from derived classes but not from outside.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` is here exactly for this purpose. Insisting not to use it for an unspecified reason is a malformed question.

If you don't want to make the field `protected` then you need at least a protected getter which returns a reference (or `const` reference):

```
protected:
  vector<char>& getLetter() { return letter; }
```

Comment: I tried both methods you suggested (protected and reference), but for some reason the vector become empty.

Comment: @Lobster: you should post a MVCE because we can't imagine your code by guessing.